# Is there a more efficient way to update values of all subfield in each key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a json data loaded into a dictionary in Python that follows the following structure:

```
data = {
    1: {
        'field1': 0,
        'field2': 2
    },
    2: {
        'field1': 0,
        'field2': 2
    },
    3: {
        'field1': 0,
        'field2': 2
    }
}
```

I would like to update the value of `field1` in all fields. Instead of doing:

```
for key in data:
    data[key]['field1'] = 5
```

Is there a way that is quicker than O(n)?

Comment: No O(n) is minimum since you have to go through all elements.

Comment: Why are all of the `field1` values `0`, and all of the `field2` values `2`?
If this is a guarantee of your structure, then you *can* do the replacement faster ... but then your structure would be a rather silly way to represent only two field values.

Comment: It should be obvious that with the current structure of the dictionary it would at least be O(n). However, you can do a hack in the string representation of the JSON by replacing `"field1": 0` with `"field1": 5`, if that makes sense to you.

Comment: @Prune, it was just an example. The actual data has much more fields than that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It is good to know.